# Как показать музыкальное искусство?

Tags: java, android, mobile-development, imageview, android-imageview

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder,  final int position) {
    int index = folderNames.get(position).lastIndexOf("/");
    String folder = folderNames.get(position).substring(index + 1);
    holder.folder.setText(folder);
```

Когда я использую этот код, он показывает изображения, но они изменены
Потому что искусство изображения не из папки.
byte[] image = getArtFolder(artFolder.get(position).getPatch());

[image: как показать музыкальное искусство?]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Добавьте пожалуйста в ваш вопрос больше деталей, и уточните проблему. Отредактируйте заголовок чтобы он соответствовал проблеме которая у вас возникла!

Comment: @Andrew отредактировано выше